# Multiply diagonal of matrix by a set of values

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

Is there any unitary transformation that has the effect of only multiplying the diagonal with some values.

For example if I start with the matrix

$$A=\left(\matrix{1&a&b&c\\d&1&e&f\\g&h&1&i\\j&k&l&1}\right)$$

Is there some unitary matrix which will transform it to

$$A=\left(\matrix{\alpha&a&b&c\\d&\beta&e&f\\g&h&\gamma&i\\j&k&l&\delta}\right)$$

where we have some target $\{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta\}$.

Comment: How are you going to apply the unitary transformation to $A$?  Are you regarding the matrix as a linear transformation and doing $A U$, or are you regarding it as an inner product and doing $U^* A U$?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I intended it to be in the form $U^*AU$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $A = I$, the identity matrix.  Then your condition says that $U^* U$ is equal to some non-identity matrix, contradicting the definition of a unitary matrix.